# Install Tensorflow in windows 8 using PIP

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

From last day I am Trying to install the tensorflow in my windows 8 system using PIP and having python 3.5 version. 
I tried to upgrade the PIP. it worked. when I try to install the tensorflow it throws an error attached below.

state that:
could not find the version that satisfies the requirement.

Comment: You forgot to add the error...

Comment: Thanks. I am not able to add an image so I added the text.

Comment: Can you add the command line command? Did you use `pip3`?

Comment: I used **pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu **

Comment: But here you do not upgrade `pip`, you aim to upgrade the package. But since there is no package, that fails. You should use `pip3 install tensorflow-gpu`.

Comment: I did that also but seems it has something missing [link](http://icecream.me/2e35d1c5836cbcd48f9a4282f13d65a3)